# Are get variables encrypted when using Tor?

Tags: onion-services, security, encryption

I'm relatively new to Tor and I was wondering if get variables in the address bar are visible to anyone other than the client and the server.

Example:

```
randomaddress.onion/login.php?a=47
```

Would anyone be able to see that `a` is `47`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Hidden Services connection encrypts everything your browser sends. The variables are just a part of address and thus cannot be read because the address is encrypted.

Comment: So not even the exit node would be able to see it?

Comment: Exit nodes would be able to see it (e.g. you are connecting to example.com without HTTPS), but no relays in hidden service circuit would see it (e.g. you are connecting to randomaddress.onion).